# MVC + Accessing hiddenfields in controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to assign a value to my hiddenfield and access it in my controllers, after assiging the value in the hiddenfield, I will perform a delete action which at the end of the function will reload the page, this is where it will access my 'SearchResult' ActionResult again, however I am not able to get the hiddenfield value, please kindly assist what I am doing wrong here. Thanks:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function storeValues() {
            var searchString = $('#searchString').val();
            $("#storeFields").val(searchString);
        }

        function confirmDeletion() {
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: '@(Url.Action("DeleteEntry", "Admin"))',
                data: '{"id": "' + delId + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (msg) {
                    if (msg.data === "success") {
                        $('#deleteModal').modal('hide');
                        $('#hideButton').hide();
                        location.reload();
                    }
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { }
            });
        }

    </script>
        <input type="hidden" id="storeFields" name="storeFields" />
        <input type="image" id="searchbutton" onclick="storeValues();" src="@Url.Content("~/images/magnifying-glass.png")" width="30" height="30"/>





        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public ActionResult SearchResult(int? page, string storeFields)
        {
            var entries = unitOfWork.EntryRepository.GetAllWinners_SearchByEmail("True", "", 1);

            var day = 1;

            var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
            var onePageOfEntries = entries.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10);

            if (day == 2)
            {
                return View("DayTwo", onePageOfEntries);
            }
            return View("Index", onePageOfEntries);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `location.reload()` you can use `window.location.replace(url)` passing the hidden field value as querystring.